# How to join COUNT(*) from another JOINed table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 databases: `Users`, `Posts`, `Comments`.

I want to perform a query that gets information of all posts

```sql
SELECT
    Posts.id as postId,
    Users.id as authorId,
    Posts.title,
    Users.displayName,
    Posts.createdAt
FROM
    Users
INNER JOIN
    Posts
ON
    Users.id = Posts.authorId;
```

returns something like

```
+--------+----------+---------+-------------+---------------------+
| postId | authorId | title   | displayName | createdAt           |
+--------+----------+---------+-------------+---------------------+
|      1 |        1 | title 1 | Alice       | 2022-07-22 16:35:39 |
|      2 |        2 | title 2 | Bob         | 2022-07-22 16:35:47 |
+--------+----------+---------+-------------+---------------------+
```

I want to join this with the result of

```sql
SELECT postId, COUNT(*) FROM Comments GROUP BY postId
```

which returns something like

```
+--------+----------+
| postId | COUNT(*) |
+--------+----------+
|      1 |        5 |
|      2 |        3 |
+--------+----------+
```

The final result I want to achieve is

```
+--------+----------+---------+-------------+---------------------+--------------+
| postId | authorId | title   | displayName | createdAt           | commentCount |
+--------+----------+---------+-------------+---------------------+--------------+
|      1 |        1 | title 1 | Alice       | 2022-07-22 16:35:39 | 5            |
|      2 |        2 | title 2 | Bob         | 2022-07-22 16:35:47 | 3            |
+--------+----------+---------+-------------+---------------------+--------------+
```

How should I write the SQL query? (I am using MySQL)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 3 tables(?) and you can try this:

```
SELECT
    P.ID AS POSTID,
    U.ID AS AUTHORID,
    P.TITLE,
    U.DISPLAYNAME,
    P.CREATEDAT,
    C.CNT
FROM
    USERS U
INNER JOIN
    POSTS P
ON
    U.ID = P.AUTHORID
    JOIN (SELECT POSTID, COUNT(*) CNT FROM COMMENTS GROUP BY POSTID) C
    ON C.POSTID = P.ID;
```

Comment: This solution is also good. In this case the subquery takes the form of a "table expression".

Answer (score 0):

You can use a subquery (a "scalar subquery") to get the number of comments for each post.

For example:

```
SELECT
    p.id as postId,
    u.id as authorId,
    p.title,
    u.displayName,
    p.createdAt,
    (select count(*) from comments c where c.postid = p.id) as comment_count
FROM
    Users u
INNER JOIN 
    Posts p
ON
    u.id = p.authorId;
```

I added aliases to the tables to improve readability.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CTE (Common Table Expressions) over here.
Below is the query:

```
with comment_count as 
(
SELECT postId, COUNT(*) as commentCount FROM Comments GROUP BY postId
),
post_processed as 
(
SELECT
    Posts.id as postId,
    Users.id as authorId,
    Posts.title,
    Users.displayName,
    Posts.createdAt
FROM
    Users,
    Posts
where
    Users.id = Posts.authorId
)
select 
pp.*,
cc.commentCount
from 
post_processed pp,
comment_count cc
where pp.postId = cc.postId;
```

Comment: Depending on the MySQL version common table expression cannot be used. MySQL supports CTE after version 8.